# how to prevent select2 clear textbox when dropdown close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to use jQuery plugin Select2. I wonder is there any way to prevent textbox clear after dropdown close wheter the search result match or not.

```js
var data = [
{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, 
{ id: 1, text: 'bug' }, 
{ id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, 
{ id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, 
{ id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

$(".test").select2({
  data: data,
  placeholder: "Find...",
   width: '100%',
   allowClear: true
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>


<select class="test"></select>
```